# Make a stack of cubes in Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I wonder if it's possible to build a stack of cubes as seen on the image:

[image]

This is what I tried (not the result I want):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way [out of many] to do it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This will do the trick. I wonder of it’s possible to make this more scalable. If you could input any number for the bottom row and the stack builds up automaticly.

Comment: I think you need a loop to do any number of stacked cubes. The upcoming Blender 4.0 will have [*Repeat Zone* nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/repeat_zone.html)

Comment: Many thanks. I guess I’ll have to wait until November.